# How to create a form checkbox without a label on LibreOffice Writer

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, forms

In default the checkbox seems to have a label assigned to it. For creating an fillable PDF I'm looking for just a plain checkbox which can be clicked -- the description is done at another column, as it's a table based designed.

When removing the orignal label, the placeholder still keeps some place for it.

Comment: What happens when you create the field with a blank label, or set the label text color to transparent or white?

Comment: It keeps a little space for the label. Approx 1 char big. Due to this fact, the checkbox is not centered  in the box.

Comment: If nothing better can be found, this would be an approach, as the centering in the box could be achieved with an asymmetric placement of the checkbox control.